# ASP.NET C# list of properties when type '=' on a property

Tags: c#, properties, intellisense

I have this class I use as searcher to pass user values to my manager method that calls a stored procedure to read users data:

```
   public class UserSearcher
{


    public UserSearcher()
    {
        this.username = null;
        this.password = null;
        this.email = null;          
        this.SortType = UserGeneric.SortType.ByKey;
        this.SortOrder = UserGeneric.SortOrder.ASC;


    }

    #region Properties
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public UserGeneric.SortType SortType { get; set; }
        public UserGeneric.SortOrder SortOrder { get; set; }

    #endregion

  }

}
```

I have this other class I use to set orderType and SortType to pass to the store:

```
public class UserGeneric
{

    // Fields
    private SortOrder _order;
    private SortType _type;

    // Methods
    public UserGenericComparer()
    {
        this._type = SortType.BySurName;
        this._order = SortOrder.ASC;
    }

    public UserGenericComparer(SortType type, SortOrder order)
    {
        this._type = type;
        this._order = order;
    }



    // Nested Types
    public enum SortOrder
    {
        ASC = 1,
        DESC = -1
    }

    public enum SortType
    {
        ByKey,
        ByUserName,
        BySurName,
        ByRegistrationDate
    }


}
```

}

My problem is that when I use the searcher:

```
UserSearcher mysearcher = new UserSearcher();
```

and I type "mysearcher.SortOrder = something" or "mysearcher.SortType = something"
I want that when I type "=" (after ysearcher.SortOrder) automatically are displayed the properties I can use without type:

```
 uso.SortType = UserGenericComparer.SortType.(List of my properties)
```

So I wanna that the intellisense should show the list of the property automatically when I type "=".

How can I do that?

thank you

Comment: Resharper supports that.

Comment: Also CodeRush can do it.

Comment: are you sure that I need to use some external plugin? I have seen this behavior in a project I worked on with other people and there was no plugin. was thinking that .NET could do it. but how?

Comment: Also.. Visual Studio does it? Isn't this basic intellisense support for enums? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, I think isn't need to use some plugin to do that.

Comment: Isn't this standard intellisense? You could try Alt+Space after the dot to 'force' the intellisense pop-up, but you shouldn't need to do that...